# What happens if a Vargouille victim dies before turning?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, character-death, curses

Title says it all, a humanoid gets the Vargouille curse, but dies before they turn.

What happens, does the curse break, or just pause like in daylight, or do they still turn in the same rate, or do they turn immediately?

(So basically, can a Revivify spell be used as a pseudo Remove Curse?)

Comment: Please let me know if you think the duplicate isn't a duplicate so that we can clarify and reopen. FYI, duplicates are okay, there can be many ways to ask similar things and the more we have, the easier it is for others to find them. And welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate here.

Comment: @NautArch The linked answer didn't touch everything I asked here, but did answer the most important part, so I'm satisfied.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, we can reopen. But ultimately, it seemed like you were asking if Death cures the Vargouille curse and if it/revivify/coming back to life acts as a *remove curse* - and that is the overall same question. But if you feel that your question is different, please clarify and we can reopen. It is identical questions that generate duplicates, identical answers to different questions should still be separate.

Comment: @NautArch it's all good, thanks